# Html5 3 column layout

Tags: css, html

I'm having problem with my website on 3 column.
I wanted it to be the content on center only which the left and right is empty.
How do i set the center column to be in center without using left-margin ?
how do i set a maximum width to the center column so content wont exceed to the right column ?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <div id="content1">

        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display:block;
}

.left, .center, .right {
    margin:0 10px;
}

.left {
    float:left; 
    width:180px;
    position:fixed;
}

.center {
    float:left;
    width:880px;
    margin-left:200px;
}

.right{
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: do you want to use `left` and `right` columns or you just need to put them as blank to make content in center.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using margin-right? Why not use padding for the 10px? And ... i think you want to keep the left and right column when scrolling, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. You could use something like [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/), or try to work with CSS flexbox which is really good, but not supported by all browsers right now, afaik!

To your code: Why do you use position: fixed? Your code should work, try to remove it please. And set overflow to auto on wrapper div.

Works: http://codepen.io/doodlebunch/pen/vGxol

```
.wrapper { 
  display:block; 
  overflow: auto;
}

.left { 
 float:left; 
 width:180px;
}

.center { 
 float:left;
 width:880px;
 margin: 0 10px;
}

.right{ 
  float:left;
  width:180px;
}
```

If you want to leave .left and .right blank you could remove them and add margin: 0 auto; to your .content-div.

```
.content { 
 width:880px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Yup , it works when you have height&width on it. But , i am leaving it blank without color , with this the center part without margin-left will move all to the left.

Comment: Then use margin: 0 auto; and remove left and right. Content-DIV should be in center then.